# Capybara - Finding a disabled button located in table row

Tags: ruby, button, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing

I have a button

```
<button type="button" id="saveListing" class="button small save-button" data-bind="enable: saveEnabled, click: save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
```

located in the tr of a table.

I wrote a function for testing the button status, simply using:

```
And(/^...the button "(.*?)" on "(.*?)" page is disabled$/) do |button_name, page|

  button_id = ConfigHelper.get_button_info(button_name, page)['id']
  button_class = ConfigHelper.get_button_info(button_name, page)['class']

  if !button_id.nil?
    find_button(button_id)[:disabled].should eq 'true'
  elsif !button_class.nil?
    find(button_class)[:disabled].should eq 'true'
  else
    button_text = ConfigHelper.get_button_info(button_name, page)['text']
    find('button', text: button_text)[:disabled].should eq "true"
  end
end
```

However, this block does not work for a button in a table row. I also tried add checking by button id, and it also did not work. How can I implement it without taking table id as a parameter? (As I don't want to write table id inside the feature)

When using id, the error is:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css ".saveListing"
```

or using text:

```
 Ambiguous match, found 4 elements matching css "button" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Does it say element not found?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have just added the error messages.

Comment: Within what context is this code evaluated. Is it the entire `page`? Also could you try to find it with an additional parameter in find `find('...', disabled: true)` or css `find('...:disabled')`?

Comment: Yes, entire page. Actually I've added "if !button_id.nil? find_button(button_id)[:disabled].should eq 'true'" check. And It couldn't find the element. I cannot add css to it, because I cannot get it in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveListing` is the **id** of your *button*, not a *class*. In *css* selectors, **dot** is used for *classes* and **hash sign** is used for *ids*.

Therefore, you should either be using `#saveListing` or `.save-button`, but not `.saveListing`. This is why your first matching fails.

---

As to why the second one does - I guess there are 4 rows, each with one button and *Capybara* doesn't know which one you are referring to. If you want to check this condition for *all* of them, you could use `all` instead of `find` like this:

```
all('button', text: button_text).each do |button|
  button[:disabled].should eq "true"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer, actually when I write "find_button('#saveListing')[:disabled].should eq 'true'" It still returns "Unable to find button "#saveListing"". Actually I am quite new to Capybara and realized that when I don't give dot or hash prefix, it assigns dot. (I am getting the button information from config file)

Comment: I have added entire function to the question.

Comment: If you are sure it doesn't find it in the context of the entire `page` with `find_button('#saveListing')`, could you try `find('#saveListing')` instead. If it is still not found, this might be a waiting issue. You could try test this by adding `sleep 5` before attempting to `find`. If you still get fail message, use [`save_and_open_page` or `save_and_open_screenshot`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging) to verify the buttons are indeed loaded and you are on the page you expected to be.

Comment: Yes using find instead of find_button just worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Capybaras find_button doesn't search css classes at all so unless you have overwritten find_button I'm not sure why you would be getting that error from using it with an id.  find_button will search by the id, value, text content, or title attribute of the button, and also supports a disabled filter for searching.  More stable (if the status of the button is changing due to JS) versions of those checks would be

```
find_button('saveListing', disabled: true).should be #Note: no # in front of the id here since its not a css selector
find_button('button text', disabled: true).should be
```

These would be more stable because they will utilize Capybaras waiting behavior to find the disabled button, whereas the way they were written previously would immediately find the button and error if they weren't yet disabled.